# SharePoint Online Notification if list item is not complete

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to create a notification that sends a weekly email to a specified user if a list item has a value of a specific state.

For instance...I want to assign an owner(s) to an item on a list and send a weekly reminder to that owner(s) if value of "Completed" isn't set to yes. Also send a weekly email of all items in the list with the value of "Completed" not set to yes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Designer to create a Weekly Reminder Workflow as the following:

- Create a new variable called `Today` then set it to **Current Date**.
- Use loop to **Loop with condition** until `complete` field become `yes`
- Now, insert `Add Time to Date` action to add 7 days to the `Today` variable (output to date variable).
- Then add `Pause` action to pause until 7 days (until date variable value).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll give it a try as soon as I can figure out why I can't use 2013 workflows on my site.

Comment: Is it SharePoint Online?

Comment: This worked great for a reoccurring reminder, after MS Support helped enable 2013 workflows. Thanks again for the point in the right direction.