# Workflow Email – Repeated Date Notification

Tags: workflow, outgoing-email

I am trying to set up a workflow that will send out an email once a date field named Roster Date is left blank and will continue to send out an email on a weekly basis until that field is populated with a date.
This is what I have so far (its doesn’t work):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Loop with condition** to create a repeatedly Reminder that will run weekly while the Roster Date is `blank` as the following:

[image]

For the detail steps, check [SharePoint Online Notification if list item is not complete](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229568/sharepoint-online-notification-if-list-item-is-not-complete/229570#229570)

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice is to use a **Custom Timer Job**, since sending emails weekly basis from a SharePoint Designer Workflow isn’t a good option. You would have to have a workflow running all day checking if *Roaster Date* column on some item has changed, I don’t think that’s a good use of a workflow.

Look at this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1ce8ad/create-custom-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013-for-send-email/) where it’s explained how to create a Timer Job to send an email. You would have to add a condition to check if *Roaster Date* column on some item has changed, then send specific mail.